Can we call stored procedures recursively? Does it necessary or recommended. If not then which approach is best suitable in same scenario?
I have an stored procedure "updateStatus".
I want to update some certain statuses in one go.
But for certain status Ids, I have to again update the next status for example if anyone called the sp with "payment-success" status, I have to call again the same sp with "completed" status. Hence I want to call recursively.
Currently I am calling this recursively.

Does it work? What are you asking? Why are you asking?

Yes, its working for me. I am asking whether this is recommended approach or we can follow some other path. I want suggestion/ recommendations

That's not a suitable question for this site as it is a matter of opinion.

If you can provide an acceptable level of recursion, it is perfectly possible to use recursion in procedures. However, you might be better off using recursion in queries inside the procedure.

Max recursion in SQL Server is 32, so that's your limit

Recursion is one of the tools in every programming toolbox... its a fundamental computer science algorithm... so I am curious as to what prompted you to ask? Do your colleagues suggest it was a bad idea?

Why not gather what you need to update using recursive cte and then do it in one shot
